# Can't retrieve post params, although they appear in firebug

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm having this issue:

I have a flash object in my page, which sends some requests to a php script.
Using firebug, I can see all post params the swf object is sending (see attached picture), but in my script, I am not able to retrieve them.

I am trying:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET); 
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

However, all are empty.

What is the clue I am missing?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: in GET and POST you get empty array? or any parameter exist?

Comment: Probably is not doing the POST to the correct PHP. Check the names.

Comment: $_POST is empty, $_GET has the one parameter shown in the url (?methid=PUT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because there is a 301 redirect (i.e. *301 Moved Permanently* on your screen shot). POST data is NOT included redirect.

Comment: hello @adrenalin, thanks for replying. What is the couse of such an effect, why would it redirect? the file is there and i can see its response. (It's just the .html with the swf and my .php script, no more file)

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde Please verify if there are `.htaccess` redirection or any other.

Comment: The issue is in the server side code and impossible to guess without seeing it. You need to trace what is making `header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently')` (or similar, depending on the server settings) and changes the page location. You can try to use `var_dump` or `print_r` before it to verify that the POST data is there, but after the headers have been sent to browser and the code has exited, POST data will not be included ever in any redirection due to HTTP specifications.

Comment: @Parixit gave a good suggestion in case you have an Apache server with `.htaccess` doing anything. That would be outside PHP scope, *albeit unlikely* because you use a REST API that didn't do anything for the previous query on your console.

Comment: This was it @adrenalin! fixing the `301 Moved Permanently` to `200 OK` did the job (.htaccess issue)! Thank you so much! Another day with a small but important lesson :)